# Understanding ER diagrams

Tags: database, entity-relationship

i try to understand ER diagrams and i came across an example that i'm not sure how to "look" at it..

Consider this diagram:
[image]

What is the difference between the above and this diagram:
[image]

From what i have learned, the last diagram says "for every couple of school and teacher, there is one and only course" . So, if i have 3 schools, 3 teachers and 3 courses, there will be 9 triplets in Teaches relationship.
What the first diagram changes? what kind of 2 triplet that exist in Teaches in the last diagram, can't be in the first diagram?

I try to first look at the diagram without constraints.So i have maximum 27 triplets (for the above example).After that, there is an order of what to do? can i first can put the rounded arrow of Course, of first to put the regulat arrow to teacher?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation you're using, referring to the semicircle on the line between Course and Teaches.  From your description, it sounds like it means Course is a non-prime element of the Teaches relation.  The arrow in Chen's notation indicates that a Teacher can't exist without teaching a Course at a School.  Course being non-prime wouldn't prevent non-teaching teachers from being recorded, thus the existence dependency is indicated separately when required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quick answer

The difference between two diagrams is the joint type of `teacher` and the relation `teaches`, which represents a

> Many-to-One
>   Partial

relationship in first diagram and a

> Many-to-Many
>   Partial

relationship in the second one.

### Explained answer

Let `R` be a relationship set between entity sets `A` and `B`. The
participation of `A` is `total` if **every entity of `A` must participate** in at least one relationship in `R`. Otherwise, the participation of `A` is `partial`.

Consider the simple diagram below:

[image]

The line connecting A and R may:

- Carry an arrow: Meaning one (as in one-to-many).
- Not carry an arrow: Meaning many.
- Be a double line: Meaning total participation.
- Be a single line: Meaning partial participation.

Comment: Does the direction of arrow matter? I have seen examples where the arrow points from A to R and in some examples the arrow points from R to A.